# How to check for Adobe flash Player installed on Mac with Applescript or Java?

Tags: java, applescript

I am trying to installl the AdobeFlashPlayer programmatically, before that i need to chk Whether if its already installed?, if yes then i need to get the version of the same. Since flash player will be added as a plugin, i need to chk the same in Safari and Firefox browsers. Pls suggest how to achieve the same using Applescripts (if possible without using SWFObjects).

Comment: would you like to find flashplayer plugin installed in safari browser?

Comment: yes.. I am still confused i don knw whether the flash player plugin will be installed in the browser or system??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a mac, browser plugins are installed in a folder called "Internet Plug-Ins". You can have this folder in the user's Libray folder or the main Library folder. So using applescript we can check those folders...

```
set pluginName to "Flash Player.plugin"
set pluginsMainFolder to (path to library folder from local domain as text) & "Internet Plug-Ins:"
set pluginsUserFolder to (path to library folder from user domain as text) & "Internet Plug-Ins:"

-- check the folders and get the version if found
set theVersion to missing value
tell application "System Events"
    try
        set f to first file of folder pluginsMainFolder whose name is pluginName
        set theVersion to short version of f
    end try
    if theVersion is missing value then
        try
            set f to first file of folder pluginsUserFolder whose name is pluginName
            set theVersion to short version of f
        end try
    end if
end tell

if theVersion is missing value then
    display dialog pluginName & " is not installed!"
else
    display dialog pluginName & " is installed!" & return & "Version: " & theVersion
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Shockwave Flash plugin will be installed in browser run the below piece of code to find out list of plugins installed in your browser

```
for( var i = 0; navigator.plugins[ i ]; ++i ) {
      if( navigator.plugins[ i ].name.toLowerCase().indexOf( name ) > -1 )
        console.log(navigator.plugins[ i ].name);
   }
```

Adobe flash player will be installed in system as well you can check in your system installed programs